# Checking Permissions on Android Location Manager

Tags: android, android-permissions, locationmanager

here is my code

```
 package com.example.decimateglitchlocation;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.widget.Toast;
import  android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;
    TextView txtLat;
    String lat;
    String provider;
    protected String latitude, longitude;
    protected boolean gps_enabled, network_enabled;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            try{
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
                txtLat.setText("Error");
            }
        }//end of if
        else{txtLat.setText("Error2");}
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude", "disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude", "enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("Latitude", "status");
    }
}
```

I use the right permissions coarse location,fine location,and internet in  manifest. It still shows up error 2 and the checking permissions is strange behaviour. please help with this problem if you could.

I have checked over and over again on the android developer and on stack overflow and the check permissions doesn't' seem to be straight forward.  I might not just be getting the jist of it.

Thanks,

Sincerely

Sean

Comment: did you forgot to post error in your question?

Comment: the code deosn't work just says error 2 (indicated on the else on the checkpermission request) on it and it should be ;pointing my location

Comment: Are both the permissions granted?

Comment: No, I believe thats what happens.  But I don't know how to get them granted.  They shoiuld work location is on on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Android M just declaring permissions in manifest is not enough. You have to implement permission model in order to successfully get the permissions granted.

Looking at your code, you are missing the permission request. Follow this [official guile](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) and implement permission model in order to get the expected result.

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
```

Check result as follows:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            //pare grantResults
            return;
        } 
    }
}
```